# Go datastore query for getting a single entity?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

The [Datastore API reference](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference) for Go has a GetAll function that returns a slice of entities. Isn't there a method that just returns the first entity found instead of a list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GetAll` executes a query that returns all entities that match query conditions. If you want to return just one, set [`Limit(limit int)`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Query.Limit) to 1.

Comment: But it'll still return an array with 1 element instead of the single object, correct?

Comment: Of course, it's the same function, it can not just change it's return type.